# drupal 7 content type and pattern content type

Tags: forms, design-patterns, drupal-7, content-type

I have 2 custom content types, where the second one is pattern I want to use when creating the first one. The pattern contains some of fields that the first one has and I want to fill the form automatically when pattern i selected.

I explain it on example: Imagine 2 type, house and house pattern. House has fields: color, number of floors, address. House pattern has just color and number of floors.

I want to add field where can be selected house pattern when creating house and all the fields pattern has will be automatically filled. There might be added more fields in the future so I need more general solution.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Although you described it as a pattern this could be done with a **reference**.

So, a House will have a reference to a House Type Node. Then, the field of the House Type will be rendered within the House node page (choose "Rendered entity" as a display formatter). This way you can add any field latter in the House Pattern node and these will be rendered to your House Nodes automatically.

You can use the [entity_reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module for this task.

Comment: Did you find a solution through this answer? If so, please consider it as acceptable or upvote it.